# jdbc logstash Change table name to today

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, logstash

I want the table name to be today's date.

For example: dbtest_2022.dbo.tbshop2_2022_08_22 auto change to dbtest_2022.dbo.tbshop2_2022_08_23

```
input {
  jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars/sqljdbc42.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "..."
        jdbc_user => "..."
        jdbc_password => "..."
        statement => "SELECT ... FROM dbtest_2022.dbo.tbshop2_2022_08_22"
        schedule => "*/14 * * * *"
        add_field => { "tag" => "mssql-test" }
        type => "mssql"
    }
}
```

I had an idea to make two requests.
In the first request, get the table id and in the second, make a request with this id.

```
statement => "SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'dbtest_2022.dbo.tbshop2_{year}_{month}_{day}') AS 'object_id' AND SELECT ... FROM table(object_id)"
```

or is there any expression in jdbc to implement this?
For example: dbtest_2022.dbo.tbshop2_now()
or can I use dbtest_2022.dbo.tbshop2_{year}*{month}*{day} in jdbc ?

Well, so that every day you don’t change the request with your hands, but somehow automate it

I am not very good at SQL. I would be glad for help or ideas on how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

I solutioned with below steps.

**1. [.profile] set Envoronment variable.**

```
...
CURRENT_YYYYMM=`date "+%Y%m`
export CURRENT_YYYYMM
...
```

**2. logstash config file**

```
input { 
    jdbc {
        ...
        FROM ${CURRENT_YYYYMM}_logs
        ...
}
```

reference :
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/environment-variables.html